# Two way binding, scope variable undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm writing an app with OnesnUI and AngularJS, using ng-model to get the input from DOM elements.

There's my code

```
<body>
  <ons-screen>
      <ons-page class="center" ng-controller="page1Ctrl">
    <ons-navigator title="Page 1">
        <div class="center">
          <h1>Pharmy</h1>
            <ons-text-input ng-model="medName" placeholder="Enter Medicine Name" style="display:block; width:100%;" id="test"></ons-text-input>
            <div style="position:relative">
                <ons-text-input ng-model="location" placeholder="Enter Location" style="display:block; width:100%; margin-top:10px;"></ons-text-input>
                <ons-icon icon="search" style="position:absolute;right:10px;top:5px;"></ons-icon>
            </div>
            <ons-button ng-click="goToPage2()"
                        style="width:10%; margin-top:10px;">
                <ons-icon icon="search"></ons-icon>
            </ons-button>
        </div>
    </ons-navigator>
          </ons-page>
  </ons-screen>
</body>
```

and trying to retrieve the value from input textbox, there's my `app.js`:

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);
        app.controller('page1Ctrl',['$scope','pageService',function($scope,pageService){
            $scope.$watch('medName',function(newVlaue){
                console.log('Watching YOU !' + newVlaue);
            });
            console.log($scope.medName);
            $scope.goToPage2 = function(){
                console.log('Going to page2 !');
                console.log($scope.medName);
                pageService.start($scope.medName);
                $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage("page2.html");
            }
        }]);
    })();
```

Why is the `medName` printed value `undefined` ?

Comment: you have `console.log($scope.medName);` at two places, where are you getting `undefined`?

Comment: ... make that _three_ places. (in the `$watch` too)

Comment: @Mritunjay in every printing command, the value is not updating

Comment: What is being typed in the `ons-text-input` bound to `medName`?

Comment: @xtofl any text, "foo bar"

Comment: Try declaring the medName variable in your controller as the first line: $scope.medName = ''; It could also be the Prototypal Inheritance gotcha as described [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: It is probably creating medName in some inner scope. I would do a `$scope.foo = {}` and then `ng-model="foo.medName"` and it should work.

Comment: @RobJacobs already tried that, it prints the initial value but doesn't update.

Comment: @JesusRodriguez although I have no other inner scopes, your method worked.

Comment: Okey, let me create a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have to name a proper pain in Angular, it would be scope inheritance.

If you have let's say `$scope.foo = "hello"` is the controller and then you create a children scope of that controller and then you try to assign a new value to `foo` that would crete a **new** `foo` inside that new scope. Your parent controller will never see the changes.

In your problem, you are not creating a new scope, but that OnsenUI is doing so maybe on the `ons-screen` or `ons-navigator`. Then your input is inside a new child scope and if you try to assign the `newMed` it is going to do so on the child scope.

The rule always is to have objects, that is called the `dot rule` (check [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)).

So if you don't want to have this problem again, always do like I told you on the comment, create something like `$scope.meds = {}` and then `ng-model="meds.newMed"` because that way, it will search for `meds` on the parents first and if it finds it, it will use it and that is what you want to do.

Here is the first example of doing it wrong: http://plnkr.co/edit/IJZOa1pXtcQePiEVMzjZ?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <foo>
    <input ng-model="name"> <br />
    Inside new scope: {{ name }}
  </foo>
  <br />
  On the parent scope: {{ name }}
```

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true
  };
});
```

Here we are a directive that is creating a new scope called foo. Then on our html, inside `<foo>` we put a `ng-model` with `name`. It reads the current scope, oh, not there, so it goes up to the controller's scope and find it. So you see `World` on the input. When you change the input, it will grab the content of it and **assign** a new value. How? It goes to its scope, and assign it. The problem is that its scope is the new scope created by `foo` and because of that, the parent will never see any changes.

Let's see example number two: http://plnkr.co/edit/BSx37PpAEbPnHfs2jr5o?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <foo>
    <input ng-model="user.name"> <br />
    Inside new scope: {{ user.name }}
  </foo>
  <br />
  On the parent scope: {{ user.name }}
</body>
```

-

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'World'
  };
});

app.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true
  };
});
```

Here, same example but with a minor change. Here we have `name` inside an object called `user`. When the input reads it, there is no difference but when it is going to **asign** a new value, it does something different, something like: Hey new scope, do you have this user object? Errr no... ok, parent, you have this user object? I do. Good, then put into it a property called `name` with this content.

Do you see the difference? Before it didn't ask it parent, it just created the `name` on the inner scope, but if you use objects, it will try to find the object first, exactly what we need.

The **TL;DR;** is: always use objects because what happened to you is that some of the directives you were using are creating new scopes and your new **assignments** are going to be created on inner scope.

Comment: I don't know angular that much but i guess this will be better with a fiddle example.

Comment: Oh, that is for sure, give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Jai done :). I hope it makes more sense for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Created a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs4ff/) to show how it is being done and working well in Angular.

The first console.log of yours will be undefined as you have not set anything in the controller

Something like

```
 $scope.medName = '';
```

would have helped.

Code Snippet of the controller that I used in the example to demonstrate:

```
function test($scope){
    $scope.medName = '';
    console.log($scope.medName);
    $scope.$watch('medName',function(newValue){
        console.log("new Value:"+newValue);
    });
    $scope.getUpdatedScope = function(){
        console.log($scope.medName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code actually works, did you type something in the actual input? It writes undefined at the beginning because it is, it's not defined in the scope, and your input value is null.

I made a jsfiddle quickly, here is the (basically your) code.
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="page1Ctrl">
        <input ng-model="medName" />
        <p ng-if="medName">{{medName}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('page1Ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.$watch('medName',function(newVlaue){
        console.log('Watching YOU !' + newVlaue);
    });
    console.log($scope.medName);
}]);
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q3z22/4/
You'll see in the console "undefined" at the beginning, and then whatever you write in the input. If you don't want that, just define in the scope by writing `$scope.medName = '';` and you'll have an empty string at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the ng-app directive somewhere?  Try adding it to the body tag, like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```