# Data binding angularjs with onsenui variable UNDEFINE

Tags: javascript, html, css, onsen-ui

I am sorry i new in onsenui and angularjs, but i will ask simple question about data binding in onsenui and angularjs, when i used variable $scope.name with ng-model in onsen ui template have return UNDEFINE, here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="simpleKamus">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css"/>
     <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <script>
               var nameApp=angular.module('simpleKamus',['onsen']);
               nameApp.controller('KamusCtrl',['$scope','$http',function ($scope,$http){
                    $scope.tes=function(){
                       alert($scope.name);
                    };

                 }]);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="KamusCtrl">
<ons-tabbar>
    <ons-tab page="english.html" label="English - Indonesia" icon="ion-chatbox-working" active="true"></ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="indo.html" label="Indonesia - English" icon="ion-chatbox-working"></ons-tab>

</ons-tabbar>

<ons-template id="english.html">
   <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">ENGLISH - INDONESIA</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

    <input type="text" ng-model="name" class="text-input text-input--transparent" placeholder="name" style="width: 100%">

    <button ng-click="tes()">tes</button>

    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
  </body>
</html>
```

when i click tes button, Why $scope.name is UNDEFINE? if i remove all onsen's tags, only tag HTML, variable $scope.name was define. i had tried the solution in link [Two way binding, scope variable undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910341/two-way-binding-scope-variable-undefined), but cannot solve this problem, i am sorry my bad english? thanks you

Answer (score 3):

You have forgot to open the tag `<ons-page>`. Your code doesn't work because the controller is not recognised after the **ons-template**, putting it in **ons-page** works. I fixed your problem modifying the code in this way

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="simpleKamus">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css"/>
     <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <script>
               var nameApp=angular.module('simpleKamus',['onsen']);
               nameApp.controller('KamusCtrl',['$scope','$http',function ($scope,$http){
                    $scope.tes=function(){
                       alert($scope.name);
                    };

                 }]);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ons-tabbar>
        <ons-tab page="english.html" label="English - Indonesia" icon="ion-chatbox-working" active="true"></ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="indo.html" label="Indonesia - English" icon="ion-chatbox-working"></ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>

    <ons-template id="english.html">
        <ons-page  ng-controller="KamusCtrl">
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="center">ENGLISH - INDONESIA</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
        
            <input type="text" ng-model="name" class="text-input text-input--transparent" placeholder="name" style="width: 100%">
        
            <button ng-click="tes()">tes</button>
    
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
  </body>
</html>
```

p.s. i suggest you to let the index page with the standard template and create a **english.html** page where to put the content. Same for the controller.

Comment: Sorry, probably I changed something by mistake while I was formatting the code, try now, should work :)

Comment: wow its work..thank you andi pavllo...I still confuse with component in onsen ui..I only copied from pattern example and used it....

Comment: @GAJIkoegajikoe, great! Please consider accepting the answer so future searchers know that the question was answered.

Answer (score 1):

In the first attempt, if you use ng-model = "$parent.name" would work well.